# Is Luigi suited for building a pipeline around lots of small files (100k+)

Tags: python, luigi

My first gut reaction is that Luigi isn't suited for this sort of thing, but I would like the "pipeline" functionality and everything keeps pointing me back to Luigi/Airflow. I can't use Airflow as it is a Windows environment.

My use-case:

So currently from my “source” folder we have 20 or so machines that produce XML data. Over time, some process puts these files into a folder continually on each machine (its log data). On any given day these machines could have 0 files in the folder or it could have 100k+ files (each machine). Eventually someone will go delete all of the files.

One part of this process is to to watch all of these directories on all of these machines, and copy the files down to an archive folder if they are new.

My current process makes a listing of all the files on each machine every 5 minutes, grabs a listing of the files and loops over the source checking if the file is available at the destination. Copies if it doesn't exist at destination, skips if it does.

It seems that Luigi wants to work with only "a" (singular) file in its output and/or target. The issue is, I could have 1 new file, or several thousand files that shows up.

This same exact issue happens through the entire process. As the next step in my pipeline is to add the files and its metadata information (size, filename, directory location) to a db record. At that point another process reads all of the metadata record rows and puts them into a content extracted table of the XML log data.

Is Luigi even suited for something like this? Luigi seems to want to deal with one thing, do some work on it, and then emit that information out to another single file.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that mine workflow works with 10K log files every day without any glitches. The main good stuff here that I have created one task for work with each file.